# How to Append queries in Power BI / Power Query with Union instead of Union All

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

When I try to combine two datasets (coming from same table with exactly the same structure), I'm using

```
Table.Combine({table1, table2})
```

Unfortunately this results in the following native SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2
```

I'd prefer to use a normal `UNION` instead... is there a way to achieve this in M?

Comment: Why are you worried about this? Do you use direct query?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get M to use `UNION` in its native query or not, but you can remove duplicate rows after a `UNION ALL` to get the same end result.

Comment: Yes, that is what I;'m using now, but it seems a bit redundant. @Aldert, both fetch IDs from the same table, which could be duplicate IDs. When I use this product for my Join later on, it could cause unwanted duplication (Inner Join).

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be to add a **Table.Distinct** ( "Remove Duplicates" ) step, following the **Table.Combine**.

Comment: Well the outcome might be the same... technically it introduces an extra select query around the union. Just looking for a way to avoid that, if possible.